# Why does a for loop in a function iterate only one letter of a string in python?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Every time I run a function with a for loop in it,the for loop only iterates through the first character.An example

```
def tin(v):            
    for x in v:
        return x
print tin("hello")
```

In this case it would be the first letter

Comment: because you return in the for loop

Comment: `v` is a sequence. If `v` is a string it iterates one character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `return` so it's returning only the first result, which is **"h"**.

Try using `yield` to return a **generator** or just save each letter to a list so you can then iterate over it to do whatever you want to.

Using **`yield`**:

```
def tin(v):            
    for x in v:
        yield x

for letter in tin("hello"):
    print letter
```

Using a **`list`** inside the function:

```
def tin(v):
    letters = list()           
    for x in v:
        letters.append(x)
    return letters

for letter in tin("hello"):
    print letter
```

Using a **`list comprehension`**:

```
def tin(v):
    return [letter for letter in v]

for letter in tin("hello"):
    print letter
```

Output for those examples is the same:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at a Python tutorial or look up what the return statement means in Python.

> return leaves the current function call with the expression list (or None) as return value. [Simple Statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt)

In short, it will evaluate the function until a return statement is found, which happens to be the first item in the loop. This is useful if you intend to break the loop early on a certain condition, but not in this case.

A better example could be:

```
>>> def tin(v):
...     values = []
...     for letter in v:
...         values.append(v)
...     return values
>>> tin("Hello")
['H', 'e' 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

This can be condensed down to (using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

```
>>> def tin(v):
...     return [i for i in v]
>>> tin("Hello")
['H', 'e' 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

If you wish to use a generator (which then can be evaluated later, use yield).

```
>>> def tin (v):
...     for letter in v:
...         yield letter

>>> list(tin("Hello"))
['H', 'e' 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

This can be condensed down to (using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)):

```
>>> def tin(v):
...     return (i for i in v)
>>> gen = tin("Hello")
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe060534c8>
>>> list(gen)
['H', 'e' 'l', 'l', 'o']
```